# mysql show Count of rows from other table in each row with two inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have three tables: `tasks`, `groups` and `items`.

- `tasks` columns: task_id, description, group (INT, replace id with name from group table), priority, deadline, date, deleted (0 or 1);
- `groups` columns: id, name;
- `items` columns: id, description, task_id;

For example:

`tasks` table:

```
1|bla-bla|group1|high|2|2014-04-15 18:09:18|NULL|0
2|bla-bla|group1|low |1|2014-05-15 18:09:18|NULL|1
```

`groups` table:

```
1|group1
```

`items` table:

```
1|item1|1
2|item2|1
3|item3|2
```

and my sql:

```
SELECT tasks.task_id, 
       tasks.description, 
       groups.name, 
       tasks.priority, 
       COUNT(items.id), 
       tasks.date, 
       tasks.deadline, 
       tasks.deleted 
FROM   tasks 
       INNER JOIN items 
               ON items.task_id = tasks.task_id 
       INNER JOIN groups 
               ON groups.id = tasks.group 
WHERE  tasks.deleted = 1 
GROUP  BY tasks.task_id;
```

this returns empty table, but if `tasks.deleted <> 1` returns all normal. I want to get all deleted tasks with count of items in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join to the `groups` table is on `name`, not `id`.  You also had a table alias called `test` in the query, which doesn't seem to be defined.  Try this:

```
SELECT t.task_id, t.description, g.name, t.priority, 
       COUNT(i.id), t.date, t.deadline, t.deleted 
FROM   tasks t
       INNER JOIN items i
               ON i.task_id = t.task_id 
       INNER JOIN groups g
               ON g.name = t.group 
WHERE  t.deleted = 1 
GROUP BY t.task_id;
```

Comment: Sorry, in the sql of the errors. group is INT (id of table group) and name substituted for the group. Then "test" is my database.